# Issue when computing fibonacci number with recursion in python

Tags: python

I have this code for computing fibonacci numbers using cache (dictionary).

```
cache = {} 
def dynamic_fib(n):
    print n
    if n == 0 or n == 1:
        return 1
    if not (n in cache):
        print "caching %d" % n
        cache[n] = dynamic_fib(n-1) + dynamic_fib(n-2)

    return cache[n]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    start = time.time()
    print "DYNAMIC: ", dynamic_fib(2000)
    print (time.time() - start)
```

I works fine with small numbers, but with more than 1000 as an input, it seems to stop.

This is the result with 2000 as an input.

```
....
caching 1008
1007
caching 1007
1006
caching 1006
1005
caching 1005
```

This is a result with 1000 as an input.

```
....
8
caching 8
7
caching 7
6
caching 6
5
caching 5
```

It looks like that after 995 storage into the dictionary, it just hangs.
What might be wrong in this? What debugging technique can I use to see what went wrong in python?

I run python on Mac OS X 10.7.5, I have 4G bytes of RAM, so I think some KB (or even MB) of memory usage doesn't matter much.

Comment: python has recursion limit.

Comment: It surprises me that this is hanging for you rather than throwing a `RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded`

Comment: @DavidRobinson After a short hang it does throws that Error on my system.

Comment: `This limit prevents infinite
recursion from causing an overflow of the C stack and crashing Python.`

Comment: How large a Fibonacci number will you be calculating, and will you tend to work your way up to that number (thus building a cache) or jump straight to it? If the latter, you will run out of memory due to the large depth of recursion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python has a default recursion limit set to 1000.
You need to increase it in your program.

```
import sys

sys.setrecursionlimit(5000)
```

From : http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.setrecursionlimit

> sys.setrecursionlimit(limit)
>
> ```
> Set the maximum depth of the Python interpreter stack to limit. 
> This limit prevents infinite recursion from causing an overflow of the C 
> stack and crashing Python.
> The highest possible limit is platform-dependent. A user may need to set the
> limit higher when she  has a program that requires deep recursion and a 
> platform that supports a higher limit. This should bedone with care, because
> a too-high limit can lead to a crash.
> ```

Comment: While this kind of solves the problem - it doesn't really solve the larger issue, or explain it.

Comment: Indeed. On my system, this runs out of memory at about 12000 due to the large number of recursive frames. It might be a good idea to use an iterative solution if that is a possible use case.

Comment: @DavidRobinson -- See my "recursive" solution (it only recurses 2 levels deep into the stack), but still caches results as the original did.

Comment: The iterative solution is still an order of magnitude faster (for a million runs with n=500, `dynamic_fib` takes 51 seconds, while `iterative_fib` takes 7).

Comment: @Tinctorius -- I'd be interested to see exactly how you're timing it.  `dynamic_fib` should cache the results meaning that it should only spend the time to calculate it once, every other time it should return the value almost immediately.

Comment: @mgilson: of course, I clear the cache between runs. I only run it multiple times to get an accurate measure for the running time. Timing every separate run is not a good idea if the running time gets close to clock granularity and timing overhead.

Comment: @Tinctorius -- But that defeats the whole purpose of having a cache there in the first place.  Of course it's slower if you're rebuilding the cache each time.

Comment: @mgilson: I think you misunderstand. Comparing a memoizing version (`dynamic_fib`) to a non-memoizing version (my iterative version) would be unfair. As I mentioned, I run the algorithm multiple times to get a more accurate estimate of the running time.

Comment: @Tinctorius -- I think I understand.  My point is that comparing a memoizing version to a non-memoizing version for only the initial run is equally unfair -- After all, the purpose of memoizing is to make it cheap on subsequent runs, not to have blazing speeds for a one and done sort of thing.

Comment: @mgilson: No, you clearly don't understand. I'm trying to see **how much time the function takes to perform the actual computation**. Because my measurement tool (`time.time()`) has a granularity (1 millisecond) that's about the same order of magnitude of what I'm measuring (the initial run is pretty fast), measuring only a single run will not provide me with very accurate results. Therefore, if I want an accurate estimate, I have to **perform the same work** multiple times, the measure it, and then estimate the running time of a single run.

Comment: So my comment "for a million runs with n=500, dynamic_fib takes 51 seconds, while iterative_fib takes 7" means "I estimate that `dynamic_fib` takes 51 microseconds, while `iterative_fib` takes 7 microseconds."

Comment: @Tinctorius -- I suppose it's possible that I don't understand you, but, I think that we're disagreeing on what a fair comparison is for this.  Lets agree to disagree (and let DhruvPathak have his comment thingy cleared up for a little while)

Answer (score 2):

You don't really gain anything by storing the cache as a dictionary since in order to calculate `f(n)` you need to know `f(n-1)` (and `f(n-2)`).  In other words, your dictionary will always have keys from 2-n.  You might as well just use a list instead (it's only an extra 2 elements).  Here's a version which caches properly and doesn't hit the recursion limit (ever):

```
import time
cache = [1,1]

def dynamic_fib(n):
    #print n
    if n >= len(cache):
        for i in range(len(cache),n):
            dynamic_fib(i)

        cache.append(dynamic_fib(n-1) + dynamic_fib(n-2))
        print "caching %d" % n

    return cache[n]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    start = time.time()
    a = dynamic_fib(4000)
    print "Dynamic",a
    print (time.time() - start)
```

Note that you could do the same thing with a dict, but I'm almost positive that a list will be faster.

---

Just for fun, here's a bunch of options (and timings!):

```
def fib_iter(n):
    a, b = 1, 1
    for i in xrange(n):
        a, b = b, a + b
    return a

memo_iter = [1,1]
def fib_iter_memo(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 1
    else:
        try:
            return memo_iter[n+1]
        except IndexError:
            a,b = memo_iter[-2:]
            for i in xrange(len(memo_iter),n+2):
                a, b = b, a + b
                memo_iter.append(a)
            return memo_iter[-1]

dyn_cache = [1,1]
def dynamic_fib(n):
    if n >= len(dyn_cache):
        for i in xrange(len(dyn_cache),n):
            dynamic_fib(i)

        dyn_cache.append(dynamic_fib(n-1) + dynamic_fib(n-2))

    return dyn_cache[n]

dyn_cache2 = [1,1]
def dynamic_fib2(n):
    if n >= len(dyn_cache2):
        for i in xrange(len(dyn_cache2),n):
            dynamic_fib2(i)

        dyn_cache2.append(dyn_cache2[-1] + dyn_cache2[-2])

    return dyn_cache2[n]

cache_fibo = [1,1]
def dyn_fib_simple(n):
   while len(cache_fibo) <= n:
        cache_fibo.append(cache_fibo[-1]+cache_fibo[-2])
   return cache_fibo[n]

import timeit
for func in ('dyn_fib_simple','dynamic_fib2','dynamic_fib','fib_iter_memo','fib_iter'):
    print timeit.timeit('%s(100)'%func,setup='from __main__ import %s'%func),func


print fib_iter(100)
print fib_iter_memo(100)
print fib_iter_memo(100)
print dynamic_fib(100)
print dynamic_fib2(100)
print dyn_fib_simple(100)
```

And the results:

```
0.269892930984 dyn_fib_simple
0.256865024567 dynamic_fib2
0.241492033005 dynamic_fib
0.222282171249 fib_iter_memo
7.23831701279 fib_iter
573147844013817084101
573147844013817084101
573147844013817084101
573147844013817084101
573147844013817084101
573147844013817084101
```

Comment: +1 for the list cache, I was writing a similar answer but yours would have won anyways :)

Comment: @l4mpi -- Don't dicts have an O(1) length check as well?  I would expect that indexing would be slightly faster with the lists since you don't have to hash (although that's cheap for ints I'd think).  Mainly, I just think that a list is a more sane data structure for this since it provides the exact same mapping that a dict would -- with less memory overhead and faster indexing

Comment: Ah you're right of course, dict lookup is O(1) as well (if there's no collisions at least). I also think a list is more sane here, a dict might be the more natural choiche though as you can only use a list for specific functions like fib / fac and similar recursive sequences. The only advantage a dict would have here is that you could sparsely populate it with precomputed values to speed up initial computation of un-cached values.

Comment: When stack space is sufficient, this solution is slower than OP's solution (5.1 seconds versus 8.8 seconds for 10000 runs with n=500)(an iterative solution takes 0.7 seconds with the same parameters).

Answer (score 1):

A recursion free version:

```
def fibo(n):
   cache=[1,1]
   while len(cache) < n:
       cache.append(cache[-1]+cache[-2])
   return cache
```

Comment: This doesn't actually cache the results for subsequent calls though, it just gives you the entire series up to `n`.

Comment: You mean `return cache[-1]`. Still, since you're only accessing the last two elements, this version performs worse than it could.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because of the limit of stack depth, which results in an RuntimeError. You can increase the stack's recursion limit by calling

```
sys.setrecursionlimit(<number>)
```

of the *sys* module.